# Need help solving system of ODEs $\frac{dx}{dt}=2y-z$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=3x-2z$, $\frac{dz}{dt}=5x-4y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE system:
$$\begin{array}{ld}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=2y-z\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=3x-2z\\
\dfrac{dz}{dt}&=5x-4y
\end{array}$$

I tried solving it, but I have a feeling that the problem is wrong, but still maybe I just can't solve it.

Comment: Do you know how to solve equations of the form $x^{'}(t) = Ax(t)$ where $x(t)$ is a vector and $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: No, do u have any notes on how to?

Comment: Yes, but I am not going to post them here, because it will take me about three hours to teach you the theory. I can tell you though that once you have learned it, it will be much easier. Like riding a bicycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your system in matrix form becomes:

$$
\dfrac{d \vec x(t)}{dt}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&2&-1\\
3&0&-2\\
5&-4&0
\end{bmatrix} \vec x(t)= A \vec x(t)
$$

and the general solution can be given in exponential form:
$$
\vec x(t)=\vec c\,e^{tA} 
$$
where $\vec c$ is a constant vector  (that can be determined if we know the initial conditions) and $e^{tA}$ is the exponential matrix ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems)).

The calculus of the exponential matrix is relatively easy if the given matrix is diagonalizable. In this case, if $A=PDP^{-1}$ than $e^A=e^{PDP^{-1}}=Pe^DP^{-1}$ where $ e^D$ is the diagonal matrix that have as diagonal elements the exponentials of the diagonal elements of $D$.

You can see an example [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/ExpMatrix.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much and just for info are there any other ways for solving this kind of problem?

Comment: A good resurce on the WEB about ODE systems is: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~schecter/ma_732_sp13/teschl_ode.pdf